# Prevent form validation in CreateView until needed

Tags: python, django, forms, django-class-based-views

I want to use the CreateView to create users and set some additional values in the Profile linked to the User model. 
Those values are ex. the city. This city value comes from another model (**City**) ForeignKeyed to the **Region** model ForeignKeyed to the **Country** model.. and so on.

Thus to select the right city, the user has to first select the right country and the right region.
My solution is: in the beginning of the view there is just the **Country** combobox selector: when the user choose the Country I submit the form via javascript and add the **Region** combobox selector. Then when the user set the **Region** combobox I will add the **City**...

I decided to submit the form because I do not want to lose the other values in the page each time the user change some combobox using a GET and an url parameter. However I do not want to validate or display any error until the user clicks the Submit button.

So I have this

```
$('#id_of_the_countries_combobox').change(
   function () {
      $('#id_nocommit').prop('checked', true);
      $('#mainform').submit();
});
```

I want to check in my view if **nocommit** exists and just skip the validation:

```
class CandidatiCreate(CreateView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        post = request.POST.copy()
        if 'nocommit' in post:
            self.object = None
            form_class = self.get_form_class()
            form = self.get_form(form_class)
            ♯at this point form is already validated and full of errors
            return self.render_to_response(
                self.get_context_data(form=form))

        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

Problem: the form is always validated and the view shows the errors.

How can I avoid that? Or: is this the right way to do that?